# Python Code to find credit card payments

Tags: python

I'm a beginner PYTHON programmer and I'm writing some code, but it's not working... can you please help me find my error and correct it?

Here's my code so far:

```
balance=int(raw_input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: "))
annualInterestRate=float(raw_input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: "))
monthlyPaymentRate=float(raw_input("Enter the monthly payment rate as a decimal"))

monthInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12
monthlyPayment = monthlyPaymentRate*balance
newBalance= (balance-monthlyPayment) * (1 + monthInterestRate) #newBalance is updated balance
month=0

while month<12:
    month += 1
    monthlyPayment = (monthlyPaymentRate*balance)
    newBalance=(balance-monthlyPayment)*(1 + monthInterestRate)
    newBalance = balance
    print("Month: " + str(month))
    print("Minimum monthly payment: " + str(monthlyPayment))
    print("Remaining balance: " + str(newBalance))
```

Comment: What do you expect it to output and what is it outputting?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, the problem is `newBalance = balance`, which is discarding the calculation you keep making on the immediately prior line and replacing it with the original balance.  But it's hard to be sure when you haven't said what "error" you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you, Larry! That was the error, and it fixed the problem. It works now! YAY!

Answer (score 0):

```
balance = int(raw_input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: "))
annualInterestRate = float(raw_input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: "))
monthlyPaymentRate = float(raw_input("Enter the monthly payment rate as a decimal: "))
month = 0

while month<12:
    monthlyPayment = (monthlyPaymentRate)*(balance)
    unpaidBalance = (balance)-(monthlyPayment)
    interest = ((annualInterestRate)/(12.0)) *(unpaidBalance)
    updatedBalance = (unpaidBalance)+(interest)
    month +=1
    balance = updatedBalance
    print ('Month: '+ str(month))
    print ('Minimum monthly payment:' + str(round(monthlyPayment,2)))
    print ('Remaining Balance after one year: ' + str(round(updatedBalance,2)))
```

Comment: You should not just provide the code but also some explanation.